# Limit of sequence definition - alternate form

Tags: calculus, analysis

We're given this:

For all $N$ natural, there exists $0 < e < \frac{1}{N}$, such that for all $n > N$, $|A_n - L| < e$

Does this condition imply the series $A_n$ converges to $L$?

Does the condition stem from the definition of a limit?

-
My attempt at this:

Suppose that $A_n \neq L$, then for some $N$, $|A_n - L| = e'$

Because $0 < e < \frac{1}{N}$, and $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N}$ for some $n$, $|A_n - L| = e' > e$

Then $A_n = L$

Thanks,

Comment: I'm guessing that you meant "Suppose that $\;\lim A_n\neq L\;$..." .Regards to Tzlil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For all $N$ natural, there exists $0 < \epsilon < 1/N$ such that for all $n > N$, $|A_n - L| < \epsilon$.
>
> Does this condition imply the <s>series</s> *sequence* $(A_n)$ converges to $L$?

Yes, because this condition implies that $|A_{n+1}-L|\lt1/n$ for every natural $n$.

> Does the condition stem from the definition of a limit?

No, because this condition implies that $|A_{n+1}-L|\lt1/n$ for every natural $n$.

> would you agree this condition implies $A_n = L$ (for every $n$)?

No, try $A_n=1/n$ for every $n$ and $L=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon$, using your condition we'll then get convergence. So yes, your condition does imply convergence, and I would say it's so close to the standard definition that it stems from it, but I guess that is matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would you agree this condition implies An = L?

Comment: Yes, $\lim A_n=L$.

Comment: I did not mean lim An=L. I meant the series must be the constant L. Under the condition if I pick any distance between the series and the limit which isn't 0, it must be that for the rest of the series, that is all n, the distance is smaller than that non zero number. But this is impossible since 1/n goes to zero (it will eventually pass that non zero distance). therefore that initial distance and all following it are 0.

Comment: I can't see why the sequence would have to be constant, but you need to be more precise in your notation. Already in your condition you twice say "for all N", and if you mean something different from what I read it as, the conclusions might be different.